# Definite integral of rational function

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{3}\sin (x)-2)^2}\,dx$$

I tried with the "Partial fraction decomposition" method, but it doesn't lead me to the solution, so there must be another way to solve this out. Can any of You please help me?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412037/how-to-solve-int-limits-0-2-pi-dfracdx-alpha-beta-cos-x2/1412893#1412893

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you ask for help rather than a solution, here goes:

First step: apply the [Weiertrass t-substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution). This will get rid of the trig function (sine) and leave you with a rational function. DON'T multiply out any polynomials that occur; doing so will make the next step more difficult.

Step 2: Factor the denominator of your rational function.

Step 3: Apply partial fractions.

If you've already reached this step after properly carrying out the first two, why don't you show us the decomposition that you're trying for, and the resulting system of equations in the unknown coefficients for the numerators, and perhaps we can help you along.

Comment: Thanks, this was the kind of help I was looking for!  I ended up solving it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int \frac{1}{(\alpha+\beta \sin x)^2}dx$$

Now Put $$\displaystyle t = \frac{\beta+\alpha\sin x}{\alpha+\beta \sin x}\;,$$ Then $\displaystyle \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{(\alpha+\beta \sin x)\cdot \alpha \cos x-(\beta+\alpha \sin x)\cdot \beta \cos x}{(\alpha+\beta \sin x)^2}$

So we get $$\displaystyle \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)\cos x}{(\alpha+\beta \sin x)^2}\Rightarrow \frac{dt}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)\cos x} = \frac{dx}{(\alpha+\beta \sin x)^2}$$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)}\int\frac{1}{\cos x}dt$$

Now above we take $$\displaystyle t=\frac{\beta+\alpha \sin x}{\alpha+\beta \sin x}\Rightarrow \sin x=\frac{t\alpha-\beta}{\alpha-\beta t}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \cos x = \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{t\alpha-\beta}{\alpha-\beta t}\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}\cdot \sqrt{1-t^2}}{\alpha-\beta t}$$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)}\int \frac{1}{\cos x}dx = \frac{1}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\int \frac{\alpha-\beta t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \frac{\alpha}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt-\frac{\beta}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\int\frac{tdt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$$

So we Get Integral $$\displaystyle I = \frac{\alpha}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sin^{-1}(t)\left(\right)+\frac{\beta}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sqrt{1-t^2}+\mathcal{C}$$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \frac{\alpha}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\beta+\alpha \sin x}{\alpha+\beta \sin x}\right)+\frac{\beta}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\alpha+\beta \sin x}+\mathcal{C}$$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I =\int\frac{1}{(\alpha+\beta \sin x)^2}dx= \frac{\alpha}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\beta+\alpha \sin x}{\alpha+\beta \sin x}\right)+\frac{\beta}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)} \frac{\cos x}{\alpha+\beta \sin x}+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: (+1) for getting the correct expression for $\sqrt{1-t^2}$ in this answer.